Wordpress search every time shows no search found even data exists
I am using wordpress. What I am doing is, that when the user enters anything then it will search from the post and will show the result.
I have added static content $_REQUEST['keyword']="team"; just for an example, Every time I get it No search found.
Any idea what is the issue?
function universalSearch( $atts ) {
    global $post;
    
    $_REQUEST['keyword'] = "leanding"; // it's just an example

    if ( ! empty( $_REQUEST['keyword'] ) ) {
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            's' => $_REQUEST['keyword'],
            'posts_per_page' => 5,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
        );
    }

    $result = new WP_Query( $args );
    
    if ( $result->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $result->have_posts() ) {
            $result->the_post(); 
            $tid = $result->ID;
            echo '<p><a href="' . get_permalink( $post->ID ) . '">' . get_the_title( $post->ID ) . '</a></p>';

        }
    } else {
        echo '<p><a href="javascript:void(0)">No search found.</a></p>';
    }
    
    wp_die();
}

I have check the wp query I am getting like this
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND (((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '{a30a32c58212e0e69da1fe713200b690a215277638267d3fc914587e000d21db}leanding{a30a32c58212e0e69da1fe713200b690a215277638267d3fc914587e000d21db}') OR (wp_posts.post_excerpt LIKE '{a30a32c58212e0e69da1fe713200b690a215277638267d3fc914587e000d21db}leanding{a30a32c58212e0e69da1fe713200b690a215277638267d3fc914587e000d21db}') OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '{a30a32c58212e0e69da1fe713200b690a215277638267d3fc914587e000d21db}leanding{a30a32c58212e0e69da1fe713200b690a215277638267d3fc914587e000d21db}'))) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) ORDER BY wp_posts.post_title LIKE


Where are the occurrences of team in your Posts?

@Caleb, Team is just an example. $_REQUEST['keyword'] can be anything.

Do you have any posts which has team in their title? if yes then it should come in results.

@NarendraSishodiya, Yes, I have tried that, I am getting the value

Where are you calling this function from? Is there a reason you need to use a custom search function rather than WP's built-in search functionality?

Yes, Because whatevery the user enter the text in the input field, I have to show the output in the dropdown. I am only customize the result.
